# Issues using sqlsrv_rows_affected, it keeps returning false even when its true

Tags: php, sql, sql-server-2008

I have a query that changes a users password, and I want to check the users knows their current password before being able to change it. So it is working, I need to enter the current password before changes will be made, but my outputs are still always false, here is the code I have:

```
$passwordnew=$_POST['passwordnew'];
$password=$_POST['password'];


$password_hash = md5($passwordnew);     

$sql = "UPDATE cryptuser  SET password='" . $password_hash."'  WHERE  password = '".md5($password)."' AND userID ='" . $userid ."' ";   

//Check SQL Query       
$stmt = sqlsrv_query( $conn, $sql,array(), array( "Scrollable" => SQLSRV_CURSOR_KEYSET ));
    var_dump(sqlsrv_rows_affected($stmt));


    $rows_affected = sqlsrv_rows_affected( $stmt);

    if( $rows_affected === false) {
         die('password incorrect');
    } 

    else{
        echo $rows_affected." the password was updated.<br />";
    }


if(!$stmt) 
{
    die('An error has occured with your registration. If this is an indeliberate occurance, 
         please report this to us through the contact us page with details of the error.');
}
```

Can anyone see this won't output "the password was updated" even when it is? It always returns password incorrect (false)

Comment: I'm not familiar with the `sqlsrv_*` family of functions, but you don't seem to be outputting any errors, are you? If you did, you could know what exactly is causing the problem. (Edit: the [example in the manual](http://php.net/sqlsrv_query) explains how to do a proper sqlserv query)

Comment: To expand on Pekka's suggestion, can you try adding the following error check to your code:  if(sqlsrv_errors() ) != null) die(sqlsrv_errors());

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Probably not relevant for the author anymore, but for whoever find this question, the answer is:

sqlsrv_errors() returns a message saying "This function only works with statements that are not scrollable". The code above can be fixed by changing SQLSRV_CURSOR_KEYSET to SQLSRV_CURSOR_FORWARD or removing 'Scrollable' parameter at all.

Answer (score 0):

Astax is right...

This if a full example query of getting sqlsrv_rows_affected() working. The key is setting the sqlsrv_query() $options to array('Scrollable' => SQLSRV_CURSOR_FORWARD) in the query. If you don't have any parms just put array() in t

```
    $sql = "UPDATE TOP (1) MyTable SET name=? WHERE id=$id";
    $params = array($name);
    $options =  array('Scrollable' => SQLSRV_CURSOR_FORWARD);
    $stmt = db_mssql_query($db, $sql, $params, $options);

    $updated_rows = sqlsrv_rows_affected($stmt);


    if($updated_rows === false) {
        die(print_r(sqlsrv_errors(), true));
    } elseif($updated_rows == -1) {
        print "No Info available<br>";
    } else {
        print "Updated: $updated_rows rows<br>";
    }
```